# MySQL LN with Division

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7, I'm trying to calculate a daily return for cryptocurrencies. This calculation is `LN(Day2Close/Day1Close)`.

My table structure is below. CoinIndex includes the day-count within each coin. So the first day of BTC data has a coinIndex of 1, the first day of ETH data also has a coinIndex of 1. There is data for every day.:

```
CREATE TABLE `histoday2` (
 `id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `coinId` mediumint(7) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Crypto Compare CoinID',
 `time` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `fsym` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `tsym` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `close` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `high` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `low` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `open` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `volumefrom` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `volumeto` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `coinIndex` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `totalReturn` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

My query throws the error that LN() can contain only one operand. I'm not sure how else to structure this query:

```
SELECT coinId, time, close, 
(SELECT close, LN(A.close/close) 
FROM histoday2 
WHERE coinIndex = A.coinIndex -1 
AND coinId = A.coinId) B 
FROM histoday2 A;
```

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table histoday2;`; that's much more helpful.

Comment: that depends on what you have in close so provide some sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b19d98c23b8c84f96f88fccb8295f5be

Comment: what was the exact error you got? and are you sure the query you show got that error?

Comment: @ysth Structure added above. Exact error is `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: You only have one operand. You would get that error if you wrote `LN(a.close, close)` instead.

Comment: @Barmar Correct. I copied the wrong version of the query. Edited above.

Comment: The only change I see is from `B.close` to `close`. That would fix a different error, not this one.

Comment: @Barmar: the query does indeed report that error now.  even with an empty table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a subquery that returns two columns as an expression. A subquery expression has to return at most one row with exactly one column.

Use `JOIN` instead of returning the previous day's close and the LN in a subquery.

```
SELECT a.coinid, a.time, a.close AS close_yesteday, b.close AS close_today, LN(a.close/b.close) AS return_rate
FROM histoday2 AS a
JOIN histoday2 AS b ON a.coinid = b.coinid AND a.coinIndex = b.coinIndex - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a left join, just incase the previous day doesn't exist...

```
SELECT
  A.coinId,
  A.time,
  A.close,
  B.close   AS previousClose,
  LN(A.close/B.close) AS xxx
FROM
  histoday2 A
LEFT JOIN
  histoday2 B
    ON  B.coinIndex = A.coinIndex - 1
    AND B.coinID    = A.coinID
```

Dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02a5f3a4f20039a27c65edf913ce7b52)